# Ubuntu 18.04 Wifi Adapter Not Found

Tags: wireless, 18.04, dell, broadcom

I have seen that there are many duplicate threads similar to this one on AskUbuntu, however, none of them have helped me so I'm back to square one.

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Latitude E6430. I've confirmed that the WiFi switch is in fact, on. So that is not the problem.

My machine has the following network adapter installed:

`Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`

How do I get WiFi working on my machine? I would like to find the perfect solution, it seems this is a problem which plagues many a Ubuntu users.

Here is the output of `rkfill list`:

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
4: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Have you tried `rfkill unblock all`?

Comment: Hi @Jos does this require a reboot?

Comment: No, changes take effect immediately. However, no adapter is actually soft blocked, so it may not change anything. Have you verified that your Wi-Fi adapter is enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes I have verified that it is enabled in BIOS as well. The above rfkill has not resolved the issue

Comment: Your wifi seems to be hard blocked, i.e. blocked by hardware. Look for network key and try to press that. It is with PrtScr (at least in my Dell). For this press Fn + PrtScr

Comment: Hi @Kulfy there is no network key on my keyboard, once again, I have switched the hardware switch on and made sure my BIOS is correct, this is an issue laying within Ubuntu itself.